# Bring in Char(10) from cell value into Google Sheets Email

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a project but came across a major roadblock i am hoping someone has an answer to.  Otherwise i have to take a LONG way around it.

I have a cell with a simple formula containing a carriage return:

="Good" & char(10) & "Morning"

The cell's result looks like this:

"Good

Morning"

If i run a simple email script bringing in the cell's value, it strips out the char(10) from the cells value and returns the following instead:

"Good Morning"

Is there a way to retain the value of a cell including the char(10)?

I tried it with a message box and it still removes char(10) and gives the result:

"Good Morning"

vs the desired result of:

"Good

Morning"

Message box & Email scripts used:

```
function ShowCellValue(){
var OriginalString = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("E2").getValue();
var NewString = OriginalString.replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
Browser.msgBox(NewString); 
}

function SendEmail(){
var subject = "Subject Goes Here";
var OriginalString = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("E2").getValue();
var NewString = OriginalString.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
var recipients = "recipient@email.com";

var message = "<HTML><BODY><font size=4>" 
    + "<P>" + ""
    + "<BR>" + "Here is the value of cell E2: "
    + "<BR>" + ""
    + "<BR>" + ""
    + "<BR>" + NewString
    + "<BR>" + ""
    + "<BR>" + ""
    + "</HTML></BODY>"; 
MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
}
```

Comment: You can try this instead of Char(10). ="Good" & "\n" & "Morning". This will give you an ugly output in the sheet, however should give you the desired out in the Browser.msgBox and hopefully your email.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Unfortunately, it literally brings in  "\n" in the email body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linebreak is not lost. It's only being suppressed by `Browser.msgBox` method,  which replaces it with a space. Compare the following:

```
var str = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("E2").getValue();
Browser.msgBox(str);   // no linebreak shown
Logger.log(str);       // linebreak shown
```

Logging a string is a better way to see what it is than throwing it in msgBox.

You should test the email output directly; don't assume it will be what you see in msgBox.

If the goal is to display a text with linebreaks in msgBox, that can be done by encoding linebreaks as `\\n` strings:

```
Browser.msgBox(str.replace(/\n/g, '\\n'));
```

(This may also be helpful in email, but I'm not sure about that; depends on the email format.)

For email with  html format use,

```
str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
```

Comment: Normal,
That worked great for the message box.  Thank you so much!

I tried using it with an HMTL email and it still groups them all together unfortunately.  Do you know if there is a way around it in an email script?

Comment: Update:  Using the log trick, the log shows it should be emailing out correctly but it does not.  I tried pasting my email script here but it limits my characters.

Comment: Make the following change and try, str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'). Basically just introducing a html tag

Comment: Jagannathan thats it!  Thank you so much.