# Splitting a text string into multiple display line in an inputbox in a Google Macro

Tags: google-apps-script

Please excuse any stackoverflow mistakes as I am not a developer.
I currently have a Browser.inputBox statement in a Google Macro that I would like to break-up the text into multiple display lines using a linefeed or some special characters within the text string (i.e.; concatenate a function within a text string). The macro language does not recognize the CHAR function [CHAR(10)].

Example:

`var rangename = Browser.inputBox("Enter Range Name to Copy: (e.g.; A1, G45:G46, G45:H45, G45:Z203)");`

I would like the question on the googles screen to look as follows:

```
    Enter Range Name to Copy:

    (e.g.; A1, G45:G46, G45:H45, G45:Z203)
```

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks

Comment: New line is `\n` or use template literals.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791364/bring-in-char10-from-cell-value-into-google-sheets-email), you might need `.replace` or `\\n`